# Why When I click on submit the parameters of the form disappear?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In my google app script, i have an html page with a form whose action attribute is created dynamically based on the input values (with javascript) and i create the action url with parameters. After that i insert some input value , the action url is correctly created (i inspected code), but when i click on submit button , the action url open but without parameters.

i tried with method get, post but i have the some result, new url is opened but without parameter, only with "?" character. But if i do the same procedure with a link and href attribute, it works fine. I noticed that parameter not arrive to doget function

include file index.html and app.gs

```
<form id="myForm" action="#">
  <div class="form-row">   
       <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero" id="numero">
      </div>
    <div class="col">
     <div class="form-group">
      <select id="tipologia" class="form-control">
        <option selected>Tipologia supporto</option>
        <option >concorsi</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-get-started scrollto">Richiedi assistenza Form</button><!--NOT WORK-->
</form>
      <a href="#" id="btn" class="btn-get-started scrollto">Richiedi assistenza</a><!--WORK-->

<script>
 document.getElementById("tipologia").addEventListener("change", redirect);
 function redirect(){
   var nome =document.getElementById("nome").value;
   var numero =document.getElementById("numero").value;

   var opzioni = document.getElementById("tipologia");
   var selezionato = opzioni.options[opzioni.selectedIndex].value;  
   document.getElementById("btn").href="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxia-_rMYlvVjrlyGGd7zRcb1CD5hSYe6W-mLldzxY__8I2b3Q/exec?supporto="+selezionato+"&controllo="+numero+"&nome="+nome;
   document.getElementById("myForm").action ="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxia-_rMYlvVjrlyGGd7zRcb1CD5hSYe6W-mLldzxY__8I2b3Q/exec?supporto="+selezionato+"&amp;controllo="+numero+"&amp;nome="+nome;

   }
</script>

function doGet(e) {
 Logger.log(e.parameter.supporto);
  var supporto = e.parameter.supporto;
  var numero= e.parameter.controllo;
  var nome= e.parameter.nome;
}
```

i don't understand why the parameters disappear

Comment: It's not clear for me what you're doing, If you're refreshing the page then inputs will be gone for sure. Probably what you want is e.preventDefault and manually send the Xhr

Answer (score -1):

When you submit a form with `method="GET"` (the default), the URL specified in the `action` is used as a base.

The query string (which you added using JavaScript) is removed from it and it is replaced with one constructed with the data from the successful form controls.

Since none of your form controls have a name, none are successful, so there is no data. This gives you a blank query string.

---

Don't try to set the action with JavaScript (which you are doing incorrectly: The DOM `action` property expects a plain URL, not an HTML encoded one).

Just set the base URL in the `action` attribute and give the form controls names.

```html
<form id="myForm" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxia-_rMYlvVjrlyGGd7zRcb1CD5hSYe6W-mLldzxY__8I2b3Q/exec">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="controllo" placeholder="Numero" id="numero">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select id="tipologia" name="supporto" class="form-control">
          <option selected>Tipologia supporto</option>
          <option>concorsi</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn-get-started scrollto">Richiedi assistenza Form</button>
</form>
```

NB, your code includes `var nome =document.getElementById("nome").value;`
 but there is no matching `id` in your HTML. This would cause your JS to error.